# Error installing debugger: Failed to build gem native extension with ruby-1.9.3-p362

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

While trying run bundle for a new project, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Installing debugger (1.2.2) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p362 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.2.2/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing debugger (1.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Running `gem install debugger -v '1.2.2'` produces the same results.

I've checked the contents of the mkmf.log and gem_make.out file and they make little sense, but if requested I will post them.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: If `ruby -v` gives you `2.x`, consider using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) instead (as [stated in official documentation](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#known-issues) *only 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 are supported*).

Comment: @Lucio, byebug "requires version 2.2.x" and above. Apparently, ruby 2.0 users are left out in the complete cold for a useful debugger (which pry is definitely not).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I ran into same issue. I tried:

`bundle update debugger`

My Gemfile had this:

`gem 'debugger'`

And it worked, I did not have to change Gemfile. Output of bundle shows something like this

`...`

`Installing debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.6)`

`Installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2) with native extensions`

`Installing debugger (1.1.4) with native extensions`

`...`

Comment: I'll give this a try next time I encounter a similar error. It looks like I took the long way around to get there... ;)

Comment: What the !@#$%^... How did it work ? ;) Is it kind of using a new version of the gem?

Comment: Why I get `apple$ bundle update debugger
Could not find gem 'debugger'.` error?

Comment: I had to execute `gem install debugger-ruby_core_source`

Answer (score 16):

The solution to the problem was to simply to install the debugger-ruby_core_source gem - a [forked version of debugger-ruby_core_source by eiel on github](https://github.com/eiel/debugger-ruby_core_source).

After much trial and error (on my part), I simply

```
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source -v '1.1.6'
```

which force the inclusion of the p362 headers. Then when I ran `bundle`, debugger was successfully built with the native extensions, and bundler continued on it's merry way and so was I.

Just a note, while I've used *simply* several times, I tried several things and spent several hours to get this to work before I actually came to the *simple* solution.

Comment: Bravo! `gem install debugger-ruby_core_source` allowed me to continue on my `bundle`ing way. :-)

Answer (score 10):

Maybe it better use the bundle update, worked fine here.

> $ bundle update debugger-ruby_core_source

Consider to use update to all debugger gems:

> $ bundle update debugger

Answer (score 6):

Apparently debugger is not supported in ruby 2.* so use byebug instead.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem

Answer (score 6):

After trying for a while, I finally gave up and replaced `debugger` with `byebug`.

To use with pry:

```
gem 'pry', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'pry-byebug', group: [:development, :test]
```

You can then drop a `binding.pry` statement anywhere you want to start the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this with Ruby 2.0.0 installed via RVM. None of the other solutions worked for me.

RVM will just install with the binaries if they are available, which is faster, but debugger needs the source too

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --disable-binary
```

Comment: thank you man ... as you say "None of the other solutions worked for me"

Answer (score 1):

if you would use rvm, make sure you have the right sub version to match debase-ruby_core_source ordebugger-ruby_core_source.

i.e. 
in debase-ruby_core_source for ruby 2.0.0 only support p195 ,p247, p353,p451,p481,p576. 
above is not supported!

if your ruby version is not match the source provided. you won't be able to make it through.
(that cause "Can not find the source error!")

```
------------debase-ruby_core_source 0.6.0 vm_Core support list ----------------
../usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p0/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p195/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p247/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p353/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p451/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p481/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p576/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.0-p0/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.1-p76/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.2-p95/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.3-p242/vm_core.h
./usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.6.0/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/vm_core.h
```

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me:

```
$ rvm use 2.0
```

or to make it default:

```
$ rvm use --default 2.0
```