# Cannot install gem debugger -v '1.6.5'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Mac OSX 10.9.1, ruby 1.9.3p194, rails 3.2.13, XCode 5.0.2

Trying to do 'bundle install' but keep getting an error w/ debugger 1.6.5 (running gem install debugger -v '1.6.5' yields the same error). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Installing debugger (1.6.5) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  --with-ruby-dir
  --without-ruby-dir
  --with-ruby-include
  --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
  --with-ruby-lib
  --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1002:in `block in have_struct_member'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1001:in `have_struct_member'
  from extconf.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.1/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source.rb:21:in `call'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.1/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source.rb:21:in `create_makefile_with_core'
  from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-1.6.5/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060513/error-installing-debugger-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-with-ruby-1-9-3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
xcode-select --install
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570890/702560

Comment: This one solved it, thanks so much! (I would vote up, but I don't have enough rep yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me was to use ruby version 1.9.3.