# An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

When I run bundle install I get an error when it comes to installing the debugger gem (1.6.6). I'm using ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4.0.4. I'm relatively new to rails and am not sure what could be causing this problem.

[Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e311065b2a8b1c0a5cb8)

**Error**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
Makefile creation failed
*************************************************************

NOTE: If your headers were not found, try passing
    --with-ruby-include=PATH_TO_HEADERS      

*************************************************************

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
--with-ruby-dir
--without-ruby-dir
--with-ruby-include
--without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
--with-ruby-lib
--without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/debugger-1.6.6 for    inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-   static/debugger-1.6.6/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060513/error-installing-debugger-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-with-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: Yes, none of those solutions worked

Comment: You might be interested in using pry as a debugging tool instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15857212/474597

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**:

*Debugger* is not fully supported for Ruby *2.x.x*.

[**Issue#118**](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/118) is popular issue which addresses the same. Though it mentions that debugger 1.6.6 must be supported by Ruby 2.1.1, the users are still encountering the similar errors as you are.

Also, this is especially mentioned in their [**known issues**](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#known-issues).

You can try to follow [that discussion](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/118) to troubleshoot your problem.
Additionally, this may help:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
gem update
bundle install
```

The other solution in issue discusses the possibility of updating Ruby binary.

If nothing works, and if you can possibly change the ruby/rails versions, I can suggest my current combination:

```
ruby 2.0.0-p195
rails 4.0.0
```

They work perfectly fine with `debugger` gem.

Comment: Running the first line of code successfully installs the gem, but running gem install debugger still gives the same error

Comment: @EricFilkins just updated the answer above. This is sort of major version conflicting problem.

Comment: You should almost NEVER do `rm Gemfile.lock`.  This will update all gems, not just the problematic one.

Answer (score 0):

first, u can install like this: `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'`,it will ok this time. and than, bundle install will not block by gem of `debugger`.
I don't know why it works, but it does works for me,
by the way, bundle will install 2 version of debugger gems.
my env is ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score -1):

Remove your Gemfile.lock file

> **$ rm Gemfile.lock**
>   
> Then continue :**$bundle install**

it will solve the issue, 
This i faced when i setup CyDoc

Comment: Gemfile.lock keeps track of all gem dependency, and has gem versions to be used. If you remove this file, you may break all gem dependencies.

Comment: @Furkan Ayhan > you are correct, but the some previous installed package(version) will make problem to the new packages installation.(especially gem dependency Version)  yuo can recreate the same error : by setup CYDOC https://github.com/huerlisi/CyDoc

Comment: @FurkanAyhan > whats your opinion ?