# Ruby on Rails install bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I am trying to install an github app developed by someone else and I am getting an error. I have searched the internet and tried a ton of suggestions but none seem to work. I am running OSX 10.11, I successfully installed RoR and I can get a new app to run. This git uses ruby v 2.0.0-p195. I tried to run 'bundle update' and get a similar error. I tried suggestions from this page: [ruby-debug Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697359/ruby-debug-could-not-create-makefile-due-to-some-reason-probably-lack-of-necess)
And here:
[Error installing debugger: Failed to build gem native extension with ruby-1.9.3-p362](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060513/error-installing-debugger-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-with-ruby-1-9-3)
and a few other but no luck. I am including the entire terminal feedback in hopes someone can guide me. I am new to RoR so please help.

```
The git source `git://github.com/imagesnap/paperclip-meta` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 11.1.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using builder 3.0.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.7
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using json 1.8.3
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.48
Using addressable 2.4.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
Using cancan 1.6.10
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using rubyzip 1.2.0
Using websocket 1.2.3
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using daemons 1.2.3
Using database_cleaner 0.7.2
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using debugger-ruby_core_source 1.3.8
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using eventmachine 1.2.0.1
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using lumberjack 1.0.10
Using nenv 0.3.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using hashie 3.4.3
Using mini_magick 4.5.1
Using mixpanel-ruby 2.2.0
Using bundler 1.13.2
Using sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.1.1
Using pg 0.18.4
Using rspec-support 3.4.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using sequel 3.20.0
Using temple 0.7.6
Using will_paginate 3.1.0
Using faker 1.0.1
Using activesupport 3.2.22.2
Using braintree 2.59.0
Using rack-cache 1.6.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using rack-mobile-detect 0.4.0
Using sinatra 1.0
Using sprockets 2.2.3
Using rest-client 1.6.9
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using launchy 2.2.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using childprocess 0.5.9
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using zip-zip 0.3
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 1.2.7
Using foreman 0.78.0
Installing debugger 1.6.8 with native extensions
Using thin 1.6.4
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using notiffany 0.0.8
Using pry 0.10.3
Using money 6.7.0
Using rspec-core 3.4.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1
Using slim 3.0.6
Using activemodel 3.2.22.2
Using active_utils 2.2.3
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using delayed_job 3.0.3
Using factory_girl 3.2.0
Using taps 0.3.24
Using mail 2.5.4
Using letter_opener 1.4.1
Using aws-sdk-v1 1.66.0
Using xpath 0.1.4
Using selenium-webdriver 2.53.0
Using listen 3.0.6
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8/ext/ruby_debug
/Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161015-62818-19849qb.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
./231/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `open'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `copy_file'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:486:in `copy_file'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:403:in `block in cp'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1585:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1569:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:402:in `cp'
    from extconf.rb:83:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/workplace/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: try `gem install debugger-ruby_core_source` then `bundle install`

Comment: No difference, same result, got error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102043/822256

Comment: I had already tried the suggestions on stackoverflow.com/a/14102043/822256 but no luck. There is something I am missing and I do not know if it is just that I am green or what.

Comment: OK, here's where I am at: Both good news and bad. Out of desperation I started from scratch. I re-cloned the git and checked the gem.lock file where is said it was bundled with 1.11.2, so I installed it and ran bundle install and Yah!. BUTTTT... could not create the db. I have ruby 2.3.1p112 installed along with ruby 2.0.0p195. 2.3.1 server starts just fine but the app using 2.0.0 gives errors when I run rake db:create or ruby server. I found this article but thier tips are not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused

Comment: you are getting `PG::ConnectionBad` error or something else ?

Comment: check if your postgres service is running or not `netstat -l | grep 5432`

Comment: Used the Postgres App to start the db and now all is working fine!